# Using bind-value on change event in two places?

Tags: data-binding, blazor, webassembly

I have something like this where I am binding a value in the child component from the parent component.

```
<div class="col">
    <Child @bind-InputValue="@parentInputValue"/>
</div>
```

I need to know when the child has changed that InputValue so I can invoke a method in the parent because there are other components that need to be updated based on the values in parentInputValue.

I've tried binding InputValueChanged, but that throws me an error because it says it is used in two or more places. I'm guessing that the @bind-InputValue sets that up already.

The question I have is - can I somehow catch that event in my parent component? There are around 12 different inputs in that child component and I want to somehow catch an event when the child changes anything in the parent InputValue object.

I've also tried setting up some parameter in the child called OnChange that I would invoke if anything changed, but I'm using these weird dropdown things that make it hard to make that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when I need to do that I used a [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) implementation:

```cs
    public class Model: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _value;
        public string Value 
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
            }
        }
    }
```

```cs
<div class="col">
    <Child @bind-InputValue="@model.Value"/>
</div>
@code {
   private Model model = new Model();
   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
        model.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => 
        {
             Console.WriteLine($"Model {e.PropertyName} has changed.");
        };
   }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of using INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm using it for another project to do something similar. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: I know, we lossed our old windows developper reflexes -;)